# Django URL Pattern Results in 404 Not Found Error stripe succeed

Tags: django, axios

I'm working on a Django project with a payment processing feature and encountering a "404 Not Found" error when making a request to a specific URL. I've set up my URL patterns and views, but the request to `/dashboard/services/payment/success/` is not being found. On the platform of stripe the payments are successful and I receive a confirmation in the console log. Here's the relevant code and error log:

```
[30/Dec/2023 21:33:10] "POST /dashboard/services/payment/success/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4949 
Error notifying backend:"Request failed with status code 404"
```

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ... other URL patterns ...
    path('payment/', views.make_payment, name='make_payment'),
    path('payment/success/', views.payment_success, name='payment_success'), 
    path('payment/success_page/', views.payment_succeed, name='payment_succeed'), 
]

@login_required
def make_payment(request):
    if not request.user.is_client:
        messages.error(request, "Only clients can make payments.")
        return redirect('services:dashboard')

    diagnostic_requests = DiagnosticRequest.objects.filter(client=request.user, payments__isnull=True)
    if not diagnostic_requests.exists():
        messages.info(request, "You have no unpaid diagnostic requests.")
        return redirect('services:dashboard')

    total_cost = diagnostic_requests.aggregate(Sum('service__cost'))['service__cost__sum']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
            # Initialize Stripe API
            stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

            # Create a Stripe Payment Intent
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=int(total_cost * 100),  # Convert to cents
                currency='usd',
                payment_method_types=['card']
            )

            # Return the client secret in a JSON response
            return JsonResponse({'client_secret': intent.client_secret})

        # Create a Payment record
        payment = Payment.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            stripe_payment_intent_id=intent.id,
            paid_amount=total_cost,
            currency='USD'
        )

        # Link payment with all diagnostic requests
        payment.diagnostic_requests.set(diagnostic_requests)

    # Handling GET request
    return render(request, 'services/payment.html', {
        'diagnostic_requests': diagnostic_requests,
        'total_cost': total_cost
    })


@login_required
@csrf_exempt  
def payment_success(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        payment_id = request.POST.get('payment_id')

        # Retrieve the payment object
        payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, stripe_payment_intent_id=payment_id)

        # Check if the payment is associated with the current user
        if payment.user != request.user:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Unauthorized'}, status=401)

        # Update the payment status to 'Completed'
        payment.status = Payment.COMPLETED
        payment.save()

        # Retrieve and update all diagnostic requests linked to this payment
        diagnostic_requests = payment.diagnostic_requests.all()
        for request in diagnostic_requests:
            # Update each request as needed, e.g., change a status field
            # request.status = 'Paid'  # Example status update, adjust according to your model
            request.save()

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Payment processed successfully'})

    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Invalid request'}, status=400)

@login_required
def payment_succeed(request):
    return render(request, 'pay_success.html')


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const stripe = Stripe('stripe puclic key');
        const elements = stripe.elements();
        const card = elements.create('card');
        card.mount('#card-element');

        card.on('change', function (event) {
            const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            if (event.error) {
                displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
            } else {
                displayError.textContent = '';
            }
        });

        const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            fetchClientSecret().then(function (clientSecret) {
                stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
                    payment_method: { card: card }
                }).then(function (result) {
                    console.log('confirmCardPayment response:', result);
                    if (result.error) {
                        console.log('Payment error:', result.error.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Payment succeeded:', result.paymentIntent.id);
                        axios.post("{% url 'services:payment_success' %}", {
                            payment_id: result.paymentIntent.id
                        }, {
                            headers: {
                                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                                'X-CSRFToken': getCsrfToken()
                            }
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response.data.message);
                            // Redirect to the success page
                            window.location.href = "{% url 'services:payment_succeed' %}";  // Replace with your success page URL
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.error('Error notifying backend:', error);
                            // Handle error...
                        });

                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('Error after confirming card payment:', error);
                });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching client secret:', error);
            });
        });
    });

    function getCsrfToken() {
        const csrfTokenElement = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]');
        return csrfTokenElement ? csrfTokenElement.value : '';
    }

    function fetchClientSecret() {
        const csrfToken = getCsrfToken();
        return axios.post("{% url 'services:make_payment' %}", {}, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data.client_secret;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching client secret:', error);
            // Consider handling the error instead of throwing it
        });
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the error comes from `payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, stripe_payment_intent_id=payment_id)`.  You have `payment_id = request.POST.get('payment_id')`, which I suspect might be empty.  Try `print(request.POST)` to see if that is the case.  If so, the data might be in `request.body`, so try `print(request.body)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

Change below line

```
payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, stripe_payment_intent_id=payment_id)
```

To

```
payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, stripe_payment_intent_id=int(payment_id))
```

.